# Why isn't there a rule that says "any criticism should begin with saying something positive"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I like using Stack Overflow but have a very bad taste in my mouth from what I consider the "SO Police" and I don't mean that in a positive way.  I'd say at least half of the assaults on my posts (yes, I do mean that in a derogatory way) have been unfounded and in many cases wrong. I feel they can be quite condescending and unhelpful. I suggest the following:

1. Insist all criticism of posts begin with something positive about the post
2. Have the criticizer start with the assumption that the post author is smarter then the criticizer
3. Assume that the intent of the post is not evil or bent on destroying the sanctimonious nature of SO.

Comment: `Insist all criticism of posts begin with something positive about the post`  How are you going to enforce this or any of them?

Comment: How are any rules on SO enforced?

Comment: "your post isnt *nearly* as stupid as it could be"  thats positive, no?

Comment: You didn't adhere to your own rules (I don't consider *I like using satckoverflow* your positive thing to say first here). You are making huge assumptions, call the community names ("SO Police" is clearly not meant to be a positive, supporting term), and I am missing any presumptions on the level of intelligence of the community being greater than your own.

Comment: I like unicorns. This is a terrible idea.

Comment: I skimmed through your ten latest questions and found no sign of such comments. Maybe you could provide an example, so we can have an idea of the kind of comments you deem derogatory?

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that this will become an official rule, but it helps to teach by example. If you try to interact with other SO users in a positive, helpful manner, others may follow your lead. However, the goal should not be "positivity" for its own sake, but rather to help users unfamiliar with the site improve their questions without insulting them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685978/heuristically-figuring-out-whether-im-running-ipad1-or-ipad2 is an example

Comment: @PeterKellner `outright attack on my question` - where?

Comment: @PeterKellner: seriously I find your first comments on that question more questionable than those from others.

Comment: Look, it's bad enough filtering out the bad questions as it is.  You seriously propose to add yet more work for SO contributors as they struggle to find something positive to say in reply to [1000's of rubbish questions]?

Comment: @Peter, I read the comments under that question and (assuming there weren't more hostile ones that were deleted) I believe you may be taking them too seriously. Asking for clarifications about "heuristically" or pointing out you ought to solve your memory issues globally instead of trying to detect problematic platforms look like positive suggestions to me, not "attacks" on your post.

Comment: ..like this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469447/cannot-concatenate-int-and-string-in-c

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi , this was from a few years ago and I wrote a post on my blog about why it bothered me.  Maybe not the best example but that does attempt to explain it in more detail.  http://peterkellner.net/2011/12/31/stackoverflow-really-annoyed-me-this-morning/

Comment: You smell nice but this is stupid.

Comment: Let me explain what happens when you are consistently nice. friendly and considerate - you will be taken for a ride and mugged by those who are not nice.  This already happens A LOT on SO.

Comment: @PeterKellner I have to agree with bluefeet, where is the *"outright attack on my question"*? Reading your blog post as well suggests to me that you do seem to have a chip on your shoulder. Unfortunately the link points to a deleted question so I can't comment further.

Comment: @PeterKellner - To be honest, that blog post seems pretty insulting to a couple of people who were trying to help. nnnnnn was merely asking for clarification, and your response was to insult them. Likewise, Mitch was pointing out that perhaps a better way to go would be to address the root cause of your issue, and you chose to mock him as well. It's probably healthier to start off by assuming commenters mean to help, rather than taking every comment as a personal insult.

Comment: The attitude in the blog post is astounding. As is the attitude on display in your own responses. Either you're set on interpreting anything as an attack or as "not nice", or you might have to adjust your own behaviour before asking others to do so.

Comment: @PeterKellner I agree with what you want. Let's make comments more frequently useful, informative, constructive, and mostly civil. Great. *How* do we do this? Your proposal needs to suggest ideas about *how* this could be achieved, what new system or feature could ensure users comments are more civil, or constructive. Rather than just simply suggesting it's required. We know this would be good - how do we do it? eg lower threshold & increase punishment for users with X comments deleted due to "rude/offensive" or "not constructive". EG a 2 day ban if 5 such comments deleted within 2 days. (etc)

Comment: You probably would have been really excited about [the "Summer of Love"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summer-of-love).

Comment: @BradLarson you points are valid.  My frustration was based on my question pretty much being ripped to pieces and no constructive answer given.  Looking at the post now, it's very clear that the question was overwhelmingly reject by StackOverflow. I still think the question was reasonable and did not deserve the fate it received.  It was not a duplicate.  It was deleted and down voted 3 times.

Comment: @PeterKellner There is nothing 'reasonable' about calling people the 'SO Police'.  This is of course my personal opinion, but I'd put good money on the fact of your question not being well received being your own attitude concerning it, as well as the insulting blog post you made.  As well of course, as the question itself(like SO police, as noted above).  On top of that, you don't provide any mechanisms to solve this issue you see, and expect us to do all the work.  This is continued as I'm running out of characters now.

Comment: @PeterKellner To continue from my previous comment, your suggestions also have a high chance of making things more difficult for us in the end.  1) I wouldn't say this is always possible, nor do I think it should be a requirement, in that it could generate what could be perceived as snark. 2) I fall back to my earlier snark notation. 3) I have never seen this, and if you're going to bring it up as a point, I'll demand examples where this has happened.(of course, discounting obvious trolling, we do get it from time to time).

Comment: What kinds of assaults are you talking about?

Comment: "Something positive", but this suggestion isn't very well researched or constructed.

Answer (score 34):

If you find rude comments being left on your posts, flag them and we will remove them. If they are particularly bad, or if the person behind them has a history of rude behavior, we will step in and take additional action.

This is how we enforce civility on the site, we expect others to help us out and point out rude or abusive comments. A [refined "Be Nice" policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) is already being implemented to make clear what behavior is not acceptable on Stack Exchange.

I should point out that terse but constructive criticism can often be read as being hostile, because we lack the interpersonal cues to tell that the other person means well. Sometimes the brevity of the comment format can lead to misunderstandings like this. However, outright rudeness is fairly easy to pick up when flagged.

Comment: That's a fair comment Brad.  What motivated to post this morning is that I recognize the value of SO. I don't think enough of the folks answering questions realize how one snarky answer can ruin the karma associated with fifty good ones.  I guess that is what motivated me to post.

Comment: I don't think enough of the folks asking questions realize how one selfish, inconsiderate 'do my work/Google/debugging for me' question can ruin the karma associated with fifty good ones.

Answer (score 16):

I wish this was how it worked, the world would be a better place. But it's simply not practical to make it a rule. Two problems I see right off the bat:

1. How in the world are you going to enforce this? Ask people to flag them (and moderators to handle even more stuff)? Or are you going to build a criticism-positivity-ratio detector?
2. So you make this a rule (maybe you built that detector). You're going to lose some valuable contributors (sad but true), and the people that are left are either going to:

   1. Simply prefix everything with a generic positive thing (The weather is nice here!), or
   2. Just not comment at all, and we lose some potentially important advice.

My theory: Let the nice people be nice, and people will generally notice it and reward them. The blatantly offensive comments, flag them.

Comment: Like any community, the leaders set the culture and the culture can change.  If the leaders make clear what is expected and demonstrate what I list above (unless of course the really don't like what I'm suggesting and I can accept that) then I believe the tone will change.  I don't see any effort in that direction.  It takes extra effort to be civil and promote good natured exchanges.  Had the early unix folks realized this, unix would probably have won (IMHO).  SO reminds me of those early unix folks.

Answer (score 2):

Quote Peter Kellner:

> Like any community, the leaders set the culture and the culture can
>   change.    If the leaders make clear what is expected and demonstrate
>   what I list above then I believe the tone will change. I don't see any
>   effort in that direction.

Let's say you are the leader of Stack right now. What would you do to enforce comments remain civil?
Bearing in mind, you are making rules or policies to enforce this across millions of users!

Put your suggestions in your question so everyone can agree or disagree with what will be a proposal.
If you have a solution or ideas, make them known and we can chew the fat and see if something good can be implemented.

Anything which is a good idea and will improve the site and user satisfaction will be welcomed by most.

### Requirement for introducing new policies/features

To introduce order is easy, if you are going to be hard or harsh, and not care about *various* other aspects of what makes a community a *great* one which works well and advances for the better.

You have to consider many things to ensure your *ruling* is for the greater good. If you do not, then you are a dictatorship wanting your own satisfactions, and not for the community in general.

How do you achieve this while retaining equality, and free speech, and a manageable system which devs can work with and users can use and understand?

How do you ensure the majority of the community is ok with this new system, and accepts it without making some just leave the site for good?

Plus *many* other considerations.

Besides, Stack is not exactly *anarchy* now is it? If a user's comments are reported enough, they get noticed, and punished/asked to stop.

Their comment is also removed if flagged and is justifiable.

---

Besides all that, if someone is being a d1ck, ignore them, move on, let them waste their time and you remain constructive with yours.

Stack is full of clever users (for the best part) who are busy doing their own things, working on large projects, etc.  So when someone's comment seems sharp, harsh, and/or blunt, and so potentially rude, remember they are probably just posting a minimum required to be fast and give some quick and *to the point* info.

Many take the comments and other things to heart, and often, when discussions ensue, the original commenter apologises and stated "no insult intended, was just being factual".

---

Sure, strive for a Utopia, but how do you achieve this without becoming a bad dictatorship or creating tyranny?